# binding-associations in KitchenSink

Tags: json, rest, extjs, associations

I am trying to get [Kitchen Sink binding-associations](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/examples/kitchensink/?classic#binding-associations) working with
a couple of test tables being served up through an API, and unfortunately am not having any luck. I'm using ExtJS 6.20.

My models are:

```
Ext.define('md_registry.model.Patient', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'mrn', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'birth_data', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'sex', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'first_name', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'last_name', type: 'string' }
    ],

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/patientview/api/read',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'result'
        }
    }

});
```

and

```
Ext.define('md_registry.model.Procedure', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        { name: 'procedure_id', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'proc_code', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'proc_name', type: 'string' },
        {
            name: 'patientId',
            reference: {
                parent: 'md_registry.model.Patient',
                inverse: {
                    autoLoad: false
                }
            }
        }
    ],

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/procedureview/api/read',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'result'
        }
    }

});
```

While my panel with the association grids based on the Kitchensink example is:

```
Ext.define('md_registry.view.main.ListAssociation', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.binding-associations',
    width: 500,
    height: 300,
    referenceHolder: true,
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },

    viewModel: {
        stores: {
            patients: {
                model: 'md_registry.model.Patient',
                autoLoad: true
            }
        }
    },
    session: {},

    items: [{
        title: 'All Patients',
        xtype: 'grid',
        bind: '{patients}',
        reference: 'patientGrid',
        flex: 1,
        columns: [{
            text: 'First Name', dataIndex: 'first_name', flex: 1
        }, {
            text: 'MRN', dataIndex: 'mrn'
        }]
    }, {
        title: 'Procedures',
        xtype: 'grid',
        bind: '{patientGrid.selection.procedures}',
        flex: 1,
        margin: '0 0 0 10',
        columns: [{
            text: 'Proc Code', dataIndex: 'proc_code'
        }],
        viewConfig: {
            emptyText: 'No procedures',
            deferEmptyText: false
        }
    }]
});
```

The patients store is loading just fine, but it is not loading the procedures store.

The JSON for the patients store that is returned on the request looks like:

```
[{
    "birth_date": "1962-07-30T00:00:00",
    "first_name": "Phil",
    "id": "8F6AC8467F3822492A1ADF5D90EB",
    "last_name": "Schaff",
    "mrn": "00605911",
    "sex": "M"
}, {
    "birth_date": "1903-05-07T00:00:00",
    "first_name": "Charles",
    "id": "55BE732E665B3DC40A9B38EC560A",
    "last_name": "Parker",
    "mrn": "00515954",
    "sex": "M"
}]
```

While the data that *should* be returned as the procedures store from the API look like:

```
[
  { 
    "patientId": "55BE732E665B3DC40A9B38EC560A", 
    "proc_code": "97162", 
    "proc_name": "Blood count; complete (CBC)", 
    "procedure_id": "09F9A8886A1BAD5A3B65CBF4F0C0"
  }, 
  { 
    "patientId": "8F6AC8467F3822492A1ADF5D90EB", 
    "proc_code": "93.54", 
    "proc_name": "Application of splint", 
    "procedure_id": "0D601F45F5ECAC3ED44EF7B3701F"
  }, 
  {
    "patient_id": "8F6AC8467F3822492A1ADF5D90EB", 
    "proc_code": "99206", 
    "proc_name": "Antibody screen, RBC, each serum technique", 
    "procedure_id": "11C34881646C0CB6FC7DEF2EF718"
  }, 
  {
    "patientId": "8F6AC8467F3822492A1ADF5D90EB", 
    "proc_code": "99206", 
    "proc_name": "Antibody screen, RBC, each serum technique", 
    "procedure_id": "20393DF4CDEA38F7E954760887A5"
  }, 
  { 
    "patientId": "55BE732E665B3DC40A9B38EC560A", 
    "proc_code": "99207", 
    "proc_name": "Aldolase", 
    "procedure_id": "74692AFBED2317E87746C199906A"
  }, 
  { 
    "patientId": "8F6AC8467F3822492A1ADF5D90EB", 
    "proc_code": "99207", 
    "proc_name": "Aldolase", 
    "procedure_id": "76DE627192C6ABA747697C84EBE6A458"
  }]
```

I have a feeling this has something to do with my `id` being a string and not an int. Unfortunately, the data are from an EHR and this is the primary key structure with which I need to deal.

If it's not the `id`, then why isn't this working? The only response that I get from the API, as noted above, is for the Patients store through the model proxy. The associated Procedures store is not present when I look in the JAvaScript console [image: JavaScript network resources]

If anyone can spot the reason why this is not working that would be great.

*----- UPDATE-----*

If I add this store definition to my ListAssociation view, I now can see the requested JSON from the API:

```
procedures: {
                model: 'md_registry.model.Procedure',
                autoLoad: true
            }
```

However, I am still unable to display the associated data in the Procedures grid.

*----- UPDATE 2-----*

I changed the `patientId` definition in my Procedure model to this:

```
{
    name: 'patientId',
    reference: {
        parent: 'md_registry.model.Patient',
        inverse: 'procedures'

    }
}
```

And, now when I click on a patient, it is grabbing the procedures from the API, except it is the entire list of procedures, NOT the subset of procedures that should link back to a particular patient by the `patientId.` However, to confuse matters, it *is* grabbing the right `patientId` from the procedures store, and displaying it in the Procedures grid. It is just linking to ALL the procedures.

I have checked the data that is being passed from the API and it is right. It just looks like ExtJS is not doing the join between Patient and Procedure correctly.

Interesting!

Comment: I assumed filtering of the already returned JSON for the associated records would happen on the client side, but, alas, no.

From https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?311894:

"Filtering has to be done on the server side based on the "filter" query string parameter you get from the client side."

So, it looks like I need to send a request with the filtering parameter to my server. What a PITA!

Comment: The question then is how do I build a dynamic URL and pass it to the model that has the manyToOne relationship so that I get the filtered data I want when I click on the grid... Building the API endpoint is easy enough, it's the client-side stuff that is confusing.

Comment: Never mind! Apparently the URL is built with the filter. Now, I just need an API endpoint for it.